# Max file upload size in Play framework 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

When I upload large files (greater than 1 MB) in **play framework 2.0** I get

**"413 Request Entity Too Large" error.**

Could you please anybody suggest how to get rid of this?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**
I have solved this issue by adding this to application.conf

#Set Max file size

parsers.MultipartFormData.maxLength=10240K

Comment: `parsers.MultipartFormData.maxLength=x` in `application.conf` doesn't seem to work on Play 2.2.x

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with values larger than 2GB.  I used 4096M and I uploaded a 3.96 Gb file and it still failed.  no 413 error but when I tried to call 
<!-- language: lang-java -->
    `RequestBody body = request().body();
    MultipartFormData formBody = body.asMultipartFormData();`

formBody was null.  This leads me to believe there is some hard limit to the upload size.  I'm trying ot upload 4-6Gb sized files.

Answer (score 18):

See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaBodyParsers

or Java version: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/JavaBodyParsers

extract:

```
// Accept only 10KB of data.
def save = Action(parse.text(maxLength = 1024 * 10)) { request =>
  Ok("Got: " + text)
}
```

And you can configure this in your `application.conf` using `parsers.text.maxLength`.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help. I am a Java guy. My problem was to convert above lines to Java. Anyway thanks.

Comment: "`parsers.text.maxLength` is deprecated, use  `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer instead`" (Play 2.4)

Answer (score 17):

`parse.multipartFormData` and `parse.temporaryFile` don't take `maxLength` as argument letting you increase or decrease the default like `parse.text(maxLength)` does.

But you can use `parse.maxLength(maxLength, wrappedBodyParser)` instead:

```
// accepts 10 MB file upload
def save = Action(parse.maxLength(10 * 1024 * 1024, parse.multipartFormData)) { request =>
    request.body match {
        case Left(MaxSizeExceeded(length)) => BadRequest("Your file is too large, we accept just " + length + " bytes!")
        case Right(multipartForm) => {
            /* Handle the POSTed form with files */
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of BadRequest it would be more suitable to use EntityTooLarge.

Answer (score 11):

For play version 2.4.x:

> For parsers that buffer content on disk, such as the raw parser or multipart/form-data, the maximum content length is specified using the **play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer** property, it defaults to 10MB. The multipart/form-data parser also enforces the text max length property for the aggregate of the data fields.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaBodyParsers

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I got the error on an AJAX request (It was a long text). For requests like this, you can set the property:

**parsers.text.maxLength=1024K**

More information on play documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaBodyParsers

Answer (score 0):

I am using an `AnyContent` Parser. I had to change to `controller` code to following as the configurations didn't work for me

```
 def newQuestion = silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.maxLength(1024 * 1024, parse.anyContent)(ActorMaterializer()(ActorSystem("MyApplication")))) { 
    implicit request => {
      println("got request with body:" + request.body)
      val anyBodyErrors: Either[MaxSizeExceeded, AnyContent] = request.body
      anyBodyErrors match {
        case Left(size) => {
          Future {
            EntityTooLarge(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.entityTooLarge")(langs.availables(0)))))
          }
        }
        case Right(body) => {

          //val body:AnyContent = request.body
          val jsonBodyOption = body.asJson
}
}
```