# Limiting upload size in Play Framework 2.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

In Play Framework you could limit upload size by adding:

```
parsers.MultipartFormData.maxLength=[limit]
```

in application.conf. But it doesn't seem to work with current version of Play Framework. How do I do this in 2.2 version?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327499/max-file-upload-size-in-play-framework-2-0

Comment: @ChristophWulf the answer on that question doesn't seem to work in Play 2.3

Answer (score 7):

In Play 2.2

```
parsers.text.maxLength=[limit]
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length

In Play 2.4

```
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=[limit]
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length