# null request body for large data

Tags: java, http, post, playframework

I am sending large amount of text in the body of post method.
I use Postman for testing that.
However its working fine and i can read request body like this:

```
String text = request().body().asText();
```

But when i try to send large amount of data in the body i get null for the text.
I also tried using the string builder but i also get null.

```
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(request().body().asText().getBytes());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Is there a way to get that fixed??

Comment: The data you are trying to post is bigger than 128k (the default in Play)? If so change it adding to aplication.conf `parsers.text.maxLength=4M`, for example

Comment: @Salem in that case i dont think play continues with the controllers logic. Instead i think it throws a bad request or something like that. This is an example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327499/max-file-upload-size-in-play-framework-2-0)

Comment: thanks, adding parsers.text.maxLength=4M to application.conf worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

By default Play limits the upload data size to 100kb to text parsers(*). This can be changed to a bigger value globally using `parsers.text.maxLength` in `application.conf`

```
parsers.text.maxLength=4M
```

or in a specific Response or Action using

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = TheBodyParser.class, maxLength = 4 * 1024 * 1024)
public Result upload() {
    // (...)
}
```

or

```
def upload = Action(parse.text(maxLength = 4 * 1024 * 1024)) { request =>
  // ()
}
```

(*) To parsers that buffer content (ex multipart form) the limit is 10MB and can be changed using `parsers.disk.maxLength`