# HTTP 413 when using Scala and the Play WS API to POST large JSON requests

Tags: json, scala, rest, playframework, akka

When using the Play WS API and Scala to POST JSON to a remote end point, the WS post call fails with a 413. Given this means "Request entity too large" it is no surprise that this works fine with a smaller payload POST'ing to a remote end point.

When the Play code is running on the same server as the end point then the POST'ing of the exact same large JSON works.

Is it possible to steam large requests to the remote end point or does the problem lie with the network and there is a cap on sending n bytes of data to a remote end point?

The version of Scala is 2.10.3 and the Play version is 2.3.7.

The calling code is below:

```
def postRequest(request: MyRequest): Future[MyResponse] = {
  invoke(request).map { resp =>
    if (resp.status == Status.OK) new MyResponse("OK")
    else throw new RuntimeException("web service call http status not OK")
  }.recover {
    case NonFatal(e) => throw new RuntimeException("web service call failed for an unknown reason", e)
  }
}

def invoke(request: MyRequest): Future[WSResponse] = {
  val endPoint: String = s"${config.microServiceUrl}"
  WS.url(endPoint).post(Json.toJson(request))
}
```

Anybody know why this would work when the two services are running on the same server, and not when they are on separate servers?

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28225562/1205368) to see if it helps, but the problem seems to be in the remote server and not in your Play app... Try to post your data using other tool (ex curl) to see if you get the same error

Comment: Thanks Salem, yes it probably is a remote server issue. We have nginx sitting in front of the remote servers so it may well be something like a too low client_max_body_size setting. Not able to check at the mo.

Comment: Problem resolved. the default for the nginx setting client_max_body_size is 1Mb which for the payload we are sending was too low.