# Limiting upload file size in Playframework 2.2.x

Tags: file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.2

Regarding file upload in play framework 2.2.3.
According to update on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327499/max-file-upload-size-in-play-framework-2-0) question, 
adding the following to application.conf should enable upload of files upto 10MB.

`parsers.MultipartFormData.maxLength = 10240K`

this does not work for me. I get "**413, Request entity too large**" error code for any file greater than 1MB.

I tried setting another field

`parsers.text.maxLength=10M`

Still upload fails with 413.

I upload files using XHR with a FormData that a can contain multiple files.

Upload Controller Code :

```
public Result uploadAttendeeFiles(){
    try{
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    List<FilePart> uploadedFiles = body.getFiles();
    Map<String, String> returnMessages = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String fileName ="", fileExtension="", fieldId = "";
    int fileCounter = 0;

    if (!CommonUtils.isEmpty(uploadedFiles)) {
        for (FilePart filePar : uploadedFiles) {
            try {
                fileExtension = Files.getFileExtension(filePar.getFilename());
                fieldId = body.asFormUrlEncoded().get("fieldId")[fileCounter];
                fileName = body.asFormUrlEncoded().get("fileName")[fileCounter++];

                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePar.getFile());
                Object objectId = uploadService.loadFile(in, fileName, fileExtension);

                if(objectId != null)
                    returnMessages.put(fieldId, objectId.toString());
                else
                    returnMessages.put(fieldId, "failed-Failed to save file!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                returnMessages.put(fileName+"."+fileExtension, "failed-Error while uploading file!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return ok("{\"errormessage\":\"No files selected!\"}");
    }
    return ok(Json.toJson(returnMessages));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ok("{\"errormessage\":\"Error while uploading files!\"}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your upload controller method?

Comment: @thwiegan, i've edited the question with controller code

Comment: @thwiegan, i dont think there is any problem with server side code as files less than 1MB in size are uploading fine

Comment: No I was just looking for any annotation. Did you try to annotate the method directly with a specified bodyparser like: `@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.MultipartFormData.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024)` (maxLength is in Bytes)

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet. Let me see.

Comment: @thwiegan, tried it. Still the same